# How can I formally arrive at solution of "deterministic SDE"

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Let $dX_t=\mu X_t dt+\sigma X_t dW_t$.

We know that this is a shorthand for integral equation:

$X_t=X_0+\int_0^t\mu X_s ds + \int_0^t\sigma X_s dW_s$

Now: what if our equation looks like this $dX_t=\mu X_t dt+0\cdot dW_t$

According to our notation it is a shorthand for:

$X_t=X_0+\int_0^t\mu X_s ds$

Now, how can I **formally** arrive at the solution: $X_t=X_0 e^{\mu t}$, knowing that trajectories of $X_t$ might me nowhere differentiable?

Comment: Why do you think that $X_t$ might be nowhere differentiable? If $X_t$ admits this representation, then it is absolutely continuous; hence, almost everywhere differentiable.

Comment: saz, do you mean equivalence between 1 and 3: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions

Comment: Yes, exactly....

Comment: Still, $X_t$ might be not differentiable at some points... I wanted to take derivative of $X_t$ with respect to $t$ so i have: $\frac{\partial X_t}{\partial t}=\mu X_t$. Btw why somebody clicked "close"?

Comment: Well, in this particular case it's because we know that 1. the ODE has a unique solution and 2. $X_t = X_0 e^{\mu t}$ is a solution. So, the (unique) solution is obviously differentiable in $t$.